# import vs require with slashes

Tags: javascript, node.js

Note: I am on node 14.1

So I'm currently trying this line:

```
import "module-alias/register";
```

Which gives me the error

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module
```

the error pathing is:

```
node_modules/module-alias/register
```

but if I use commonjs

```
require("module-alias/register");
```

it works.

What's the difference between import and require that causes the slash to become an error?

Answer (score 1):

1) Whenever you use to import,

```
import "module-alias/register";
```

at that time Compiler will check the relative path of your module **register**, in your case if you want to use import statement in NodeJs or javascript you have to specify your usable method of their module ( it is ES6 Syntax )
eg. you have profile method in your module register then you can write something like this,

```
import { profile } form "module-alias/register";
```

2) Whenever you use require,

```
require("module-alias/register");
```

it is same as import feature but there is one difference you can't specify any specific method of your module register,( IT is Common JS Syntax )
as the above example, you can't specify the profile method of your module register.

3)

1. The difference is like import is specified specific method of any module for further use in require we can't do that.

   2. import is asynchronous and require is synchronous.
   3. Import is Syntax of **ES6 JS** and Require is Syntax of **Common JS**

Comment: I'm running it as `mjs` in node. and the error message is `node_modules/module-alias/register`

Comment: so u can write it like import "./module-alias/register";

Comment: it is a node_module

Comment: so please install module-alias as `npm i module-alias` and after that `import { register } from 'module-alias'`

Comment: that's not how the package works. You can test it yourself.

Comment: okay i worked it out by going into the node_module, it is a js file, which requires an explicit extension

Comment: okay if it is js file then you have to give file extension when you use import statement but when you use require it's okay. please refer this link example [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias)

Answer (score 0):

The difference between import and require is that import is ES6 syntax
and that's the correct syntax for it you need to import something from Ex : express-validator.

```
import { check, validationResult } from 'express-validator';
```

Also import can be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

`register` is a js file, and import requires explicit extensions thus
`import "module-alias/register";` will not work

but `import "module-alias/register.js";` will.

Answer (score 0):

import is used with ES6 and 
require is used with commonjs

1. for using import we should use, something like this

`import myObject from './File.js';`

and for exporting,

`export default myObject;`

2. for using require

`var myObject = require('./File.js');`

and for exporting ,

`module.exports = myObject;`